# Web Essentials v2.8 LESS import error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, import, less, web-essentials

For better organization, I have a main .less file that imports other .less files using the @import syntax.  In order for the Web Essentials Preview window to work I also have @import-once at the top of each .less file that imports the variables.less file.

This solution worked wonderfully until I upgraded to Web Essentials 2.8.  Now I'm unable to import any .less file that has @import or @import-once declared in it.  My main .less file no longer compiles.

If I remove the @import-once statements, the preview window is useless since I can't see the compiled CSS without importing my variables file.

I also had a case where I imported a .less file into a ruleset, as defined by lesscss.org in the [Importing into ruleset](http://lesscss.org/#-importing) section.  This also no longer works since the upgrade to v2.8.

Has anyone else experienced these issues or have a resolution?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be a <s>bug</s> -> Feature in the latest version of the WebEssentials because of a [new feature in Less 1.4.0.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17807596/736079) as Anwar describes. See [the changelog of Less](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> **1.4.0 Beta 1 & 2** (2013-03-07)
>
> - default behaviour of import is to import each file once. @import-once has been removed.

**Either**

Update your files to use the new syntax (remove the `-once` from your imports)

**Or**

To use the older version of the engine, [download the previous (2.7) version](http://vswebessentials.com/nightly/webessentials2012-2.7.vsix) and don't update until you know  it has been fixed.

**Or**

Or you can [configure your Visual Studio to look at the Nightly Build feed from Web Essentials to download the very latest version](http://madskristensen.net/post/Web-Essentials-nightly-builds.aspx) (caution, nightly builds may contain other bugs or stop working from time to time). TO do so go to Tools -> Options -> Extensions & Updates and add the feed: `http://vswebessentials.com/nightly/feed.ashx`

Which seems to add a workaround that makes it work with the old syntax as well.
[image: Add WebEssentials Nightly feed]

Comment: Here is a link to the 2.7 install if anyone needs it http://vswebessentials.com/nightly/webessentials2012-2.7.vsix

Comment: I get an error saying "The extension manifest is invalid."  Has anyone else had success opening this file?

Comment: Evidently my file association for .vsix was broken. I was able to install the extension by running "<VSInstallPath>\Common7\IDE\vsixinstaller.exe <VSIXPath>"

Answer (score 3):

In Less v1.4.0 @import-once has been removed and @import imports once by default. This means that with the following

@import “file.less”; @import “file.less”;

The second file is ignored.

I think that one is causing issue with import statements.

Comment: I agree that v1.4.0 changed the way @imports works, but the problem with Web Essentials seems to be that a less file cannot import another less file that imports other less files.    For instance, main.less cannot import foo.less that imports mixins.less and variables.less.   The reason I want to import mixins and variables is so that when working with a less file I can preview the compiled css using the Web Essentials Preview window.  If I don't import them, the preview window is useless since it can't find the referenced variables and mixins.